# Passenger not logging Ruby STDOUT/STDERR?

Tags: passenger

On a server I built within the last 6 months or so, I've noticed I haven't been able to get Passenger to log any Ruby output, nor does it print friendly error pages, even when specifying `passenger_friendly_error_pages on` in both the HTTP and Server config of the Nginx config file.

I'm using Nginx built with Passenger, and everything else has been working perfectly fine. Whnever I got an application error, it's almost impossible to get any clues from the production environment due to no error logs, stack trace or anything except for the usual "Incomplete response received from server", which is what I get in both the browser and in the passenger log.

Here's a sample of what my configuration looks like:

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/passenger-6.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_log_level 2;
    passenger_max_pool_size 6;
    passenger_min_instances 2;
    passenger_pool_idle_time 60;
    passenger_spawn_method direct;
    passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
    passenger_log_file /opt/services/nginx-1.15.8/logs/passenger.log;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile      on;
    keepalive_timeout 120;
    client_max_body_size  200M;

    ...

    server {
        listen        443 ssl;
        server_name   app.domain.local;
        root /opt/production/app/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        access_log logs/myapp.log;
        passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
        rack_env production;

        ssl_certificate            ssl/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key        ssl/example.key;

        location /scripts/ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I had to set passenger_log_level to 3. The documentation says this:

```
0 (crit): Show only critical errors which would cause Passenger to abort.
1 (error): Also show non-critical errors – errors that do not cause Passenger to abort.
2 (warn): Also show warnings. These are not errors, and Passenger continues to operate correctly, but they might be an indication that something is wrong with the system.
3 (notice): Also show important informational messages. These give you a high-level overview of what Passenger is doing.
4 (info): Also show less important informational messages. These messages show more details about what Passenger is doing. They're high-level enough to be readable by users.
5 (debug): Also show the most important debugging information. Reading this information requires some system or programming knowledge, but the information shown is typically high-level enough to be understood by experienced system administrators.
6 (debug2): Show more debugging information. This is typically only useful for developers.
7 (debug3): Show even more debugging information.
```

One would assume anything written to STDERR by Ruby would be considered at least a warning (log level 2). Odd behaviour.

Comment: In https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/log_file/#application-output-logging, says `Everything that the application writes to the stdout and stderr channels is logged to the log file`. Maybe you can also check the global nginx error log? `/var/log/nginx/error.log`